# How to configure SSL on an instance of SQL Server to allow dedicated users to remotely access it?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I have configured the instance of SQL Server to allow dedicated users to access it remotely.

Connection string `Data Source = 192.168.1.2,1433\sqlexpress;etc...` has been tested and works.

However, I have not configured the SSL to secure the communication.

How to configure SSL on an instance of SQL Server to allow dedicated users to remotely access it?

### edit 1

The dedicated user will administer its database using Sql Server Management Studio.
What I want to do is to secure the communication when he/she administers the database using Sql Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe certificates are the way to go, and it seems to be documented nicely here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898

Ideally, the users should connect to the app server (web?), and the app server should be the only device connecting to the database server. This makes it easier to secure, and easier to implement things like encryption over the network.

I would also imagine that you can encrypt the traffic from app server to database server on the chosen port by IPSEC or similar.